# SSRS- Implementing an either or paramater

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

So I have a requirement for a report where the user can select the exact batch number or if they are too lazy to remember the number they can pick the owner, the year, the month then the actual creation date of the batch.

If batch number is selected no need to select all the other stuff.

When the report starts up it starts in the opposite start state than expected.  The query for Owner is

```
IF (ISNULL(@BatchNumer, '') = '')
begin
    select distinct CashReceiptOwner as Label,CashReceiptOwner as Value
    from CashReceiptBatchPosted
end
```

I was expecting the Owner box to be active, than if batch number is not empty for it to be disabled.  That is not a huge issue as the combo box is blank, the bigger issue is that the report says it is required even though it is suppose to all blanks.  Now I don't want to check the allow null option because all that does is create a checkbox which the user has to select.

Hopefully I made that clear enough, does anyone what I am doing incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's a multivalue but its not... Do you have a datasource attached to it? if so then add the '' and do a union to have that value at the top. Nevermind. I see now.